# Duplicate Campaign Parameters Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I can't understand what i need to change to fix this issue in google analytics, i was playing with filters there but this error is still on google analytics

```
Property mysite.com is receiving hits with utm_term parameters of the same text but different letter cases.

Campaign parameters are case sensitive,
so hits with the same keyword text but different letter cases
will show up separately in reports. As an example,
the keywords "newsletter" and "Newsletter" would be considered
different and would have separate rows in reports.
Property mysite.com is receiving hits with utm_term parameters
of the same text but different letter cases,
such as MY SITE, My Site, MYSITE, Mysite.
To avoid having data from the same keywords split across multiple rows in reports,
you can set a case filter for Campaign Term on your views.
```

GA Code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-6807150-XX', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');`
```

Answer (score 1):

As you read, the problem is different letter cases.

Try to lowercase string before sending to GA.

In js you've  got toLowerCase() method. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp